# c++ read content of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

i'm new in c++ world, i just use it for litle app that help me in my work, now, i need to read the content of a folder, list the folder content, i've made a function that return a pointer with the name of every obj in the folder, but now, i don't know how to read the content of the pointer to just print it in a console, my function look like this

```
string* listdir (const char *path)
{
    string* result = new string[50]; // limit to 50 obj
    DIR *pdir = NULL;
    pdir = opendir (path);
    struct dirent *pent = NULL;
    if (pdir == NULL)
    { 
        printf ("\nERROR! pdir could not be initialised correctly");
        return NULL;
    } 
    int i = 0;
    while (pent = readdir (pdir))
    {
        if (pent == NULL)
        {
            printf ("\nERROR! pent could not be initialised correctly");
            return NULL;
        }
        //printf ("%s\n", pent->d_name);
        result[i++]= pent->d_name;
    }

    closedir (pdir);
    return result;
}
```

i've been trying to print the result of teh function

```
int main()
{
    string *dirs;
    dirs = listdir("c:\\");
    int i = 0;
    //while(dirs[i])
    //{
            //cout<<dirs[i]<<'\n';
            //++i;
    //}
}
```

but i really don't know what i'm doing, lol, some help would be perfect
thanks

Comment: Is `string` the `std::string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, dereferencing a pointer is achieved using the `*` operator, just like in 'C'.

However, there are a number of problems with your code, which I have addressed here because I was bored...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <dirent.h>

typedef std::list<std::string> dir_list;

bool listdir(const std::string& path, dir_list& result)
{
    bool retval = true;
    DIR* pdir = opendir(path.c_str());
    if (pdir == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR! pdir could not be initialised correctly" << std::endl;;
        retval = false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (dirent* pent = readdir(pdir); pent != NULL; pent = readdir(pdir))
        {
            if (pent == NULL && result.empty())
            {
                std::cerr << "ERROR! pent could not be initialised correctly" << std::endl;
                retval = false;
            }

            if (result.size() < 50)
            {// *really* limit to 50!
                result.push_back(pent->d_name);
            }
        }
        closedir(pdir);
    }
    return retval;
}

int main()
{
    dir_list dirs;
    if (listdir("C:/", dirs))
    {
        for (dir_list::const_iterator iter(dirs.begin()), end(dirs.end()); iter != end; ++iter)
        {
            std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Since you're using C++, STL, its `string` and container classes will save you a World of pointer pain!

Answer (score 5):

Examine your `while` loop condition : `dirs[i]` is a `std::string`. You are using a string object in a boolean context : would you expect `std::string` to convert to `bool` ?

My recommendation : ditch the fixed sized array and go for `std::vector`.

```
void listdir(const char *path, std::vector<std::string> &dirs)
{
    /* ... */
    while (pent = readdir (pdir))
    {
        /* ... */
        dirs.push_back(pent->d-name);
    }

    closedir(pdir);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> dirs;

    listdir("c:\\", dirs);
    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = dirs.begin(), end = dirs.end(); it != end; ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Better answer.  IMHO, should use a constructor or cast when appending to the vector; this illustrates the actual conversion.

Comment: I also think that the listdir function should return by value, not return by passed reference.

Answer (score 3):

```
int main()
{
    string *dirs;
    dirs = listdir("c:\\");
    for (int i = 0; i < 50 && dirs[i].size() > 0; ++i)
    {
            cout << dirs[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

`dirs` is a pointer to an array, so you can index it like an array.  You created an array of 50, so you need to limit yourself to 50 here too.  Since you might not have populated the whole array, the .size() check allows the printing loop to stop early.

Comment: I'm out of votes today, but this should be voted up. @Andrew's answer will fail horribly if `dirs` is full.

Comment: @marcog:  Sorry, can't downvote you; you neglected to delete the results, thus creating a memory leak.  See @icecrime's answer using `std::vector` and `std::string`.

Comment: @Thomas Technically it doesn't matter, since the deletion would be right at the end of `main()`. But it's not my answer, I was just commenting due to the accepted answer having a nasty hole. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is some major confusion in your code, especially between arrays of characters, strings and arrays of strings.  Also, there is a memory leak.

Here are my questions / concerns:

### Issues / Concerns

1. The `opendir` function may be called
   with a null parameter.  You should
   check for a null path before calling
   `opendir`.
2. Returns NULL after declaring some
   variables.  IMHO, one should check
   parameters before declaring
   variables.
3. How does one know how many valid
   entries are in the returned array?
4. If the size of the array (known only
   to the `listdir` function) changes,
   the users of the function are
   doomed.
5. Is the type of `pent->d_name` the
   same as `string *`?
6. The address of the directory name,
   `pent->d_name`, is copied into the
   results array, but not the content
   of the directory name.  The OS may
   reuse this location without telling
   you; so copying the address of the
   text is not a good idea.
7. The `main` function does not delete
   the memory allocated for the
   results.  This is known as a memory
   leak.

### Suggestions / Fixes

1. Use `std::string` within the
   function.  This takes care of
   allocating memory for text.
2. Use `std::vector<string>` for the
   results.  This takes care of knowing
   the quantity of directories and no
   need to dynamically allocate or
   deallocate memory.
3. Create a `std::string` from the
   `pent->d_name` and use `push_back`
   to append the string to the results.

Answer (score 0):

your while statement looks strange, it looks like it's expecting `dirs[i]` to be a pointer, but I believe `dirs[i]` will be a non-pointer type. Maybe change it to (assuming string is std::string):

```
while(i < 50 && dirs[i].length() > 0)
{
        cout<<dirs[i]<<'\n';
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: k, i updated my answer to do a bounds check, now please remove the down-vote! it burns, it burns!

Comment: What happens when the `listdir` function reads only 4 directories?  Whole program needs some redesign and some understanding of data structures.

Comment: @Thomas: i believe std::string ctor will set length to 0, so it would handle that case correctly - in that it would exit the loop after the fourth element in the dirs array.